# How can I set lower level of privacy in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, cookies, low-level, htmlunit, privacy

I used HtmlUnit library (version 2.8) for scrapping but the response page let me set  lower level of privacy.
How can I set  lower level of privacy in HtmlUnit?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: what do you mean by "lower level of privacy"?

Comment: Yeah, In IE, If you go into Tools/Internet Options select "Privacy" tab, scroll lower level of privacy. How we can adjust that in HtmlUnit?

Thanks, Scott

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a custom [CookieManager](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/CookieManager.html) for your [WebClient](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#setCookieManager%28com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.CookieManager%29).